# VBA in Excel: Creating a chart from ActiveX Textboxes

Tags: vba, excel, charts, activex

I'm trying to create a chart from 5 ActiveX Textboxes which I put in my Worksheet. First the user types in the values and then presses a button which generates the chart.

This is my approach but it doesn't work. It says something like "Object necessary"

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim arKurse(4) As Double

arKurse(0) = Conver.ToDouble(TextBox1.Text)
arKurse(1) = Conver.ToDouble(TextBox2.Text)
arKurse(2) = Conver.ToDouble(TextBox3.Text)
arKurse(3) = Conver.ToDouble(TextBox4.Text)
arKurse(4) = Conver.ToDouble(TextBox5.Text)


Dim oChtObj As ChartObject
Set oChtObj = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=445, Width:=385, Top:=10, Height:=245)

With oChtObj.Chart
    .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    .SeriesCollection.Values = arKurse
    .SeriesCollection.XValues = Array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5")

    .ChartType = xlLine
    .HasLegend = False
    .HasTitle = True
    .ChartTitle.Caption = "Chart"

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Where does it say that error? What is `Conver.toDouble` ? Are you defining that somewhere? Why not use the `CDbl()` function?

Comment: are your textboxes actually named `TextBox1`, `TextBox2`, etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things that don't work

1. Conver.ToDouble should be CDbl unless you have a good reason to use a custom method?
2. TextBox.Text should be Textbox.value on a userform and also best to qualify the location of the textbox with it's parent. (in this case Userform1 but could be Sheet1 if textbox is on worksheet)
3. Need to define which seriescollection

The below is updated to work hopefully

```
Option Explicit

Sub SetupUserformToTest()
UserForm1.Show
UserForm1.TextBox1.Value = 1
UserForm1.TextBox2.Value = 2
UserForm1.TextBox3.Value = 3
UserForm1.TextBox4.Value = 4
UserForm1.TextBox5.Value = 1
CommandButton1_Click
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim arKurse(4) As Double

arKurse(0) = CDbl(UserForm1.TextBox1.Value)
arKurse(1) = CDbl(UserForm1.TextBox2.Value)
arKurse(2) = CDbl(UserForm1.TextBox3.Value)
arKurse(3) = CDbl(UserForm1.TextBox4.Value)
arKurse(4) = CDbl(UserForm1.TextBox5.Value)

Dim oChtObj As ChartObject
Set oChtObj = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=445, Width:=385, Top:=10, Height:=245)

With oChtObj.Chart
    .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    'Assumed series 1
    .SeriesCollection(1).Values = arKurse
    .SeriesCollection(1).XValues = Array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5")

    .ChartType = xlLine
    .HasLegend = False
    .HasTitle = True
    .ChartTitle.Caption = "Chart"
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks that helped me... but now It says "type mismatch" ... I think the series can't take the arry?

Comment: Wait nevermind ... got it ... forgot to switch UserForm1 to Sheet1

Comment: Just a slight correction - you should be ok using TextBox.Text or TextBox.Value. They're the same thing but in VBA Value is more common across controls.

Comment: wait ... sry I was wrong this doesn't work ... when I run the code it says "activex component can't create object"